# JFrame position three buttons one below another in the center

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, layout-manager

So I would like to have three `JButtons` all on top of each other, but not to large in width or height either. I am not too familiar with Java's layouts, and to be honest I am not too keen on them. Please view the image a code below to explain to me how, thanks.

[image]

```
package com.aqagame.harrykitchener;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main 
{

    private JButton playGame, playerNames, exitGame;

    public Main()
    {

        JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        playGame = new JButton("Play Game");
        playerNames = new JButton("Player Names");
        exitGame = new JButton("Exit Game");


        mainCard.add(playGame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainCard.add(playerNames, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainCard.add(exitGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Harry's AQA game");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainCard);
        window.setSize(900, 800);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [**Java Documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for the different layout managers. I know you're not familiar with them, which is why you should probably start. Once you get used to them there is no end to their benefits. There is a lot of excellent information in the documentation and I am sure you will learn a lot. Personally, I recommend looking at the [**Box Layout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html):

[image]

Comment: `JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(mainCard, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));` I changed it to box layout and it is returning an error and underlines the second `mainCard`, how so?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? I have a feeling you tried plugging and placing, which really doesn't work very well. You'll need to set it up using the layout managers as explained in the links I posted.

Comment: I am only a student in secondary school and find it very difficult to understand the code in the documentation. Is there any chance that you may be able to explain to me how I could implement it to my code?

Comment: Skimming the documentation will not help, I know. It is very difficult to follow if you just scan through it. In order to understand it you actually have to take time to read it thoroughly, twice if necessary. On another note, you could use the BorderLayout as NESPowerGlove suggested, since it will make centering easier.

Comment: `I am only a student in secondary school and find it very difficult to understand the code in the documentation.` what part of the code do you not understand?. The tutorial provides working code with 5 buttons. Instead of us changing your code, why don't you change the tutorial code to do what your want. How hard would it be to change the code to only display 3 buttons? Also, the tutorial code is better structured, since it shows you how to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread by using the invokeLater() method.

Comment: @HarryKitchener take a look at this other [tutorial](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/uiswing/learn/example2.html) it's not that hard

Comment: Thanks guys, I finally managed to do it in a different way: `JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
  
  firstPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(300, 350, 300, 350));`, however there is no padding between the buttons, how would I do that?

Comment: `however there is no padding between the buttons, how would I do that?` - read the `GridLayout` API to see what properties you can change.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create  JPanel that uses a `GridLayout` and add all the buttons to the panel. The GridLayout will automactially size the buttons to be the same size.
2. Set the `layout manager` of your main window to use a `GridBagLayout`.
3. add the panel to the main window using the default GridBagConststraints. Then the panel will automatically be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

To not use Box or GridBag, I think a combination such as this may work out:

- Have main panel (let's call it A) have a BorderLayout
- Create another panel (let's call it B), with a FlowLayout, with constructor aligning components to the center
- Create another panel (let's call it C), with a GridLayout, 1 column 3 rows
- Add each button to a new JPanel with a FlowLayout (1 JPanel per button, so buttons are wrapped by a FlowLayout), and then add each of those JPanels to C
- Add C to B
- Add B to A (center position)

I think this should cause buttons to be on top of each other with small amount of padding while not being stretched widthwise and while appearing in the center of the screen.